# Trouble at loading package newtxtext and introducing a font family through fontspec's \newfontfamily

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, newtxtext

I need to use the character at the code point 0x021C in a document typeset on a Times New Roman-like typeface, but those available to me have the corresponding Unicode slot empty. The Junicode typeface fills the gap, though.

I would like to use the advantages of the `newtxtext` package compiling with the `xetex` engine. The following MWE works, but uncommenting the line loading `newtxtext` while commenting out the `\setmainfont` line breaks down the compilation:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily\juno{Junicode Two Beta}
%\newcommand\zeh{\juno \char"021C}
\newcommand\zeh{{\juno\symbol{"021C}}} %<- as per egreg's observation in comment below. 

\begin{document}
\zeh
\end{document}
```

How can this issue be solved so as to both load `newtxtext` and use the Junicode font? I am on Windows 10 with a recently updated MikTeX distribution.

Comment: you get `! Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Termes" cannot be found.` ?

Comment: @David Carlisle: No, the problem appears when I load `newtxtext`, commenting out the `\setmainfont` line. I do not have both lines uncommented for the same compilation.

Comment: The first error message is issued after loading `realscripts`, upon which the compilation enters `METAFONT` atttempting to load the `othello` font. What follows is a long sequence of `METAFONT` messages. Lastly, there is a complaint about `Junicode` not being found. It s installed, though, as the compilation without loading `newtxtext` attests.

Comment: you have not said what error you get, if I use newtx with xetex I get th eerror I showed (although using TeX gyre directly as in your later line works)

Comment: I switched to Junicode as I don't have Junicode beta two though. do you get the error with the Junicode font?

Comment: @David Carlisle: Your message arrived while I was typing mine about the log lines.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I do not have `Junicode`, but I have just tried with `DejaVu Serif` and the issue is the same.

Comment: load newtxtext later, it is sets defaultfontfeatures and the Extension and that disturbs the selection of following fonts (not a good idea of newtxext).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Indeed. This solved the conundrum.

Comment: It should be `\newcommand{\zeh}{{\juno\symbol{"021C)}}`. Note the additional braces. Try `\zeh A` with your code or `\zeh xyz`. In the first case you get either nothing or a weird character, in the second case `xyz` would be typeset in Junicode.

Comment: @egreg: Rightly so. It was just for testing and I was adding the surrounding braces where issuing the command in my own test file. Here I just made it as simple as I could figure for the MWE. (There is a typo in the innermost character of the closing braces, though. It should be another curly brace.)

Comment: @Marcos Yes, I see the typo: `\newcommand{\zeh}{{\juno\symbol{"021C}}}`. If you do `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` you can do `\newunicodechar{Ȝ}{\zeh}` and use `Ȝ` in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

newtxtext sets default font features and that disturbs following font selections. You can reset them after loading the package:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures = TeX}
```

Or load the package later.